# Need to fetch last dates from the query mentioned below

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have latest dates of 2017 in attandance date but its show just 2016 dates kindly plz help me

```
SELECT
added_on,
types. `type`,
student.`student_id`, student.`roll`, student.`class_id`, student.`name` AS student_name,
SUM(datewise_attandance.`total_classes`) AS SumOfTotal,
datewise_attandance.attandance_date AS attandance_date,
SUM(datewise_attandance.`status`) AS SumOfPresent,
#ROUND(((SUM(datewise_attandance.`status`)/SUM(datewise_attandance.`total_classes`))*100),2) AS percentage,
class.`name` AS class_name, student.`sex`, student.`father_name`, student.`address`,
student.`phone`, subject.`name` AS subject_name, 
#types.`type`, types.`type_id`, 
subject.`subject_id`,
#MAX( datewise_attandance.`date_to` ) AS MaxOfAtt_Date_To,
student.`session_id` 
FROM
(( class  
INNER JOIN `subject`  ON class.`class_id` = subject.`class_id` ) 
INNER JOIN  datewise_attandance # ( INNER JOIN types ON datewise_attandance.`type_id` = types.`type_id` )   
ON ( subject.`subject_id` = datewise_attandance.`subject_id` ) 
AND ( class.`class_id` = datewise_attandance.`class_id` )) 
INNER JOIN `types` ON( types.`type_id` = subject.`subject_type`)
INNER JOIN student ON ( student.`student_id` = datewise_attandance.`std_id` ) 
AND ( class.`class_id` = student.`class_id` ) 
GROUP BY student.`student_id`,
student.`roll`, student.`class_id`, student.`name`, class.`name`,
student.`sex`, student.`father_name`, student.`address`,
student.`phone`, subject.`name`,
# types.`type`, types.`type_id`,
subject.`subject_id`, student.`session_id` 
HAVING (
(
student.`class_id` = 4
AND student.`roll` = 388
AND student.`session_id` = 5
)
) ORDER BY IFNULL(subject.final_exam,0) DESC
```

Comment: This SQL query is way to convoluted. Are you sure you need so many inner joins (x6)?!

Instead of trying to fix this mess, my best advice would be to re-engineer your solution and find  simpler path, that above is spaghetti.

Answer (score 0):

You are using inner join so if there are matching records then only result will be returned for 2017. Why dont you use left join and try the same